# Closed form solution for a coupled system of 2nd order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, closed-form

I came across the following coupled system of 2nd order ODEs from the appendix of [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999111002063#s0080) :

$$r^2 f_{rr} + 2r f_r - \frac{r}{2n+1}h_r - (n+1)(n+2)f = 0$$
$$r^2 g_{rr} + 2r g_r + \frac{r}{2n+1}h_r - n(n-1)g + \frac{n}{2n+1}h = 0$$
$$(n+1)r f_r - nrg_r + (n+1)(n+2)f + n(n-1)g = 0$$

Here, $f, g, h$ are functions of r, taking finite values as $r \rightarrow \infty$ and going to zero as $r \rightarrow 0$. $p_r, p_{rr}$ denotes the first and second derivative respectively.

They have solved for this system analytically.

I understand I would have to formulate a polynomial ansatz to arrive at the solution for this equation, but it is unclear how one should make an educated guess about it. Is there a way to find out?

Comment: You should never post a question as a [problem statement question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33854/what-is-a-psq). Instead, you should provide your own attempt at solving it. You can also add relevant definitions, possible strategies, some particular examples, where is this problem from, why is it interesting and important, and other [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).

Comment: Thanks! I will edit it with more details.

Comment: Has the method of Frobenius helped?

Comment: Perhaps it would help to transform (back?) to $r=e^t$, as then the linear system has constant coefficients and can be solved with better-known methods.

Comment: A polynomial ansatz will lead to a system of coupled quadratic equations. The subtitution Lutz mentioned will lead to something more tractable

Comment: They are coupled Cauchy-Euler equations. The "educated guess" to solve this type of equation is well known.

Comment: @Aruralreader Frobenius method kept getting more and more complicated